# Warning:okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can not build an APK with the signature but can run the application and build APK release

All offices have taken place
I searched for a solution so much I could not find the result
Please help you guys
I'll send more details if you want

```
Warning:okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider
Warning:okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning:there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Error:java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
    firebaseLipVersion = '15.0.0'
    playServiceVersion = '15.0.0'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {

        }
    }


    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myappk.english"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "Version 4"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {



    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji-appcompat:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Who has a solution to this problem
I feel frustrated after all this exhausting work

Comment: Seems like you have proguard enabled for your release (`minifyEnabled true`). Either disable it or make sure to set it up correctly

Comment: Thank you for working with your advice and showing some string <string name = "Currencies" translatable = "false"> Currencies </ string> that needed to be translated or added (ranslatable = "false")
And indeed a work like magic is done thanks from the heart

Answer (score 30):

It's a problem with Android Studio version **3.1.0** and Gradle version **4.4** .

Add the following line in your `proguard-rules.pro` file to fix this issue.

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.*
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this one. REF: https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/a16ec15ee08424058b26c6bd62afc98b32df98bc

```
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

Answer (score -1):

using this code 
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.*

signed apk build but on mobile unfortunately stoped message appears and app closed not get a solution yet for this error.

unsign app work good project run successfully but signed apk is doing problem.

Answer (score -19):

The problem was resolved by changing

From

```
 minifyEnabled true
```

to

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Thank you for working with [David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak)  advice and showing some string  Currencies  that needed to be translated or added (ranslatable = "false") And indeed a work like magic is done thanks from the hear

Comment: Even though this might solve the issue, it is just a workaround and shouldn't be used. What if I need to have minify enabled?